# Where is the best place to start learning LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have read my first book on c# and feel completely clueless about LINQ. Please suggest reader-friendly linq material.

Thanks

Comment: Which book did you read?

Comment: Accelerated C# and now I am on C# in depth..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LINQ in Action](http://linqinaction.net/) has been recommnded to me by several people.

Answer (score 2):

Download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and play with it. It comes with many free samples.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft created LINQ. So why not start with [the Microsoft documentation about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

As a reference guide [Pro Linq](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597893) is IMO the best one.

Once you are more experienced and want to know more of the internals [Programming Linq](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books/10827.aspx) is the book you want.

Also there are some great blogs out there, [Matt Warrens](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/), and [Bart De Smets](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/) are wonderfull resources for advanced Linq topics.

But the absolute best place to start as a beginner is the [101 linq samples site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx), and actually try them out.

Answer (score 1):

Charlie Calvert from Microsoft wrote a great blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2006/10/29/technical-links-to-linq.aspx) which gives you a good insight into coding with LINQ.

I hope that helps.

Ian.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Jon Skeet's "C# In Depth".  He walks you through the updates .net 2 and 3 which you need to understand to fully appreciate what's going on with Linq.  You may also have seen his name around here :)

Comment: Jon's book is great, but I think he deferes to "LINQ in Action" for more details on LINQ.

Comment: I defer to LINQ in Action when it comes to details for LINQ to SQL and similar providers. I think I give a fairly good description of the translation of query expressions to "normal" code, and the LINQ to Objects operators.

Comment: I found that once I had understood the material in Jon's book the "Link In Action" book was a very quick read -- more of reference than anything else.  Jon's book had explained the magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

And I didn't really use this tastes-like-SQL(tm) syntax and use good old mix of methods and lambdas like

```
list.Where(n => n.Something == searchingFor)
    .Select(n => new { Whatever.... })
    .OrderBy(xxx)
```

Works the same, uses same features, but look less ackward to me. And for the guide I use Intellisense.